# Set of finite graphs with R: "is a sub-graph of" is a POSET

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that the set of finite graphs with $R$: "is a sub-graph of" is a POSET

I know a POSET is a set with a reflexive/anti-symmetric/transitive relation, but how can I show such a thing? I don't know how to work with graphs very well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that:

1. every graph is a subgraph of itself
2. if $G$ is a subgraph of $J$, and $J$ is a subgraph of $G$, then $G$ and $J$ are actually the same graph
3. if $G$ is a subgraph of $J$, and $J$ is a subgraph of $K$, then $G$ is a subgraph of $K$

Now: I think these are trivial properties. Where do you have difficulties in proving these?

Comment: It looks so simple when you say it! Thanks